# Angular files on dist folder concat into one file benefits

Tags: angular, build, concat

Tengo una duda con respecto a los ficheros: the polyfills.js, main.js, runtime.js and scripts.js, que se generan en una aplicación de angular en la compilación.

¿Porqué en algunos entornos estos ficheros se concatenan en un único fichero llamado, por ejemplo, app.js? ¿Cuáles son los motivos? ¿Mejor rendimiento?¿Es mejor tener un sólo fichero en entornos de producción?

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Saludos